# Getting "Cannot write to" message after successful mirroring of remote directory with wget

Tags: wget

I have been trying to mirror a directory on my server using wget, then afterward update the downloaded tree with only newer files. The local machine is running MacOS 12.6.3; the server is CloudLinux, Version 6.

The server is semi-private, meaning, it is not password protected, but is not advertised and has a no robots suggestion.

I wanted to use something simpler than setting up rsync (ssh keys etc). The [suggestions I found here on the Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/download-only-recently-modified-files-with-wget-over-ftp) seemed a simple way to do this.

So I ran this command:

```
wget -m -e robots=off https://example.com/folders
```

("folders" directory has an `Options +Indexes` directive in `.htaccess`)

This created the initial target.  Everything downloaded fine, and created the initial "folders" directory tree on my local machine, with all files appearing intact.

Then, I created a new file within the tree on the server that I originally downloaded, then tried running this to see if it would pick up the new file:

```
wget -m -e robots=off --timestamp https://example.com/folders
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot write to ‘example.com/folders’ (Success).
```

Full output:

```
--2023-12-24 05:29:07--  https://example.com/folders
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 123.456.789.123
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|123.456.789.123|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example.com/folders/ [following]
--2023-12-24 05:29:07--  https://example.com/folders/
Reusing existing connection to example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3671 (3.6K) [text/html]
example.com/folders: Is a directory

Cannot write to ‘example.com/folders’ (Success).
```

I checked permissions of the folder mentioned and they are fine.

Doing a search for the "Cannot write to" message yielded a bunch of results unrelated to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure why it works, but please try to add a slash (`/`) after the URL
like so to get to behave as expected:

```
wget -m -e robots=off https://example.com/folders/
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you.